# custom position for data-title?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am using the data-title attribute to "hint" the user of what element he is seeing.

The problem is that thanks to my divs, the title is not shown properly, just part of it, like if the the rest was being showed behind of the other div.

Is there a way to make the title appear in front of everything, and let's say, give it a custom position?

Thanks in advance.

edit:

this is the code for the css

```
a {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

a[data-title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

well I solved part of the problem, it was the "z-index". just had to deleve the px, so now at least it is shown in front of all elements.

the problem now it is that thanks to the div it is shown far away from the mouse

so, how can I make it appear next to the mouse, just like a normal title?

Comment: @hjpotter92 there it is.

Comment: also write essential html and JS(if any).

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a [jsFidlle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), because the code as it is shown here doesn't show any flaws so far.

Comment: @LinkinTED as you said, it doesn't show any flows, the problem are my divs, but if I change them, everything will move, how can I make it act like a normal title?